# U-Boot SPL Debug Messages

Tags: u-boot

I've been trying to get U-Boot SPL to print debug messages.  I've noticed plenty of `debug()` functions that aren't printing to the serial console, however when I define the `DEBUG` preprocessor macro, I still don't see those messages.

Is this something the SPL can even do?  Especially since the serial console is initialized in `preloader_console_init()` can any messages be sent before that function is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your UART is configured correctly, you should see messages once preloader_console_init has been run.  Prior to that, you can (depending on your platform) see about getting DEBUG_UART to function in your environment.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  I had some debug messages that were supposed to print before `preloader_console_init()`